# Utility class saving reference to interface bad?

Tags: java, oop

I was looking over a class that was responsible for downloading data from a website or getting it from the local database if download failed.

My question is since downloadListFromServer in this case is an asynchronous call, wouldn't it be bad that we're doing this.listener = listener;?  Because the method could be called again before the initial call makes use of listener.  Essentially changing the reference held in listener before the first download could make use of it.

Would it not be better to do modify downloadListFromServer to accept a listener and pass that along from getList?

Note code is stripped out, so even though it looks like it we would not want to call downloadListFromServer directly in our case.

```
private MyListnernType listener;

public void getList(TextListType type, MyListnernType listener){


    this.listener = listener; // is this bad?


    downloadListFromServer(type);  // uses 
}

private  void downloadListFromServer(final TextListType type){

    Downloader.getTextList(type, new DownloadListener() {

    @Override
    public void downloadSucceeded( int statusCode, String response) {
        listener.getTextListSucceeded(response);    
    }

    });
}

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bad idea. The listener should be passed as argument to the second method.

It would be acceptable to keep the listener as a field if your object must download several files and always warn the same listener. But then the listener should be passed to the constructor of the object, or to a `setListener()` method, which would make clear that you can't pass two different listeners for two different messages.